# How to pass data from one controller to other controller in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have seen various post on stack-overflow and I try to flow, but some mistake I am doing while creating services below is my code kindly help me to find out where I am doing wrong

```js
angular
.module('yolomd', ['ngSanitize']);
app.factory('myplacementdata', function () {
    var mydata = {

      placementdata = [],
      getplacementdataValue:function () {
         return mydata.placementdata; 
      },
      setplacementdataValue: function (data) {
        mydata.placementdata = data;
      }
    }
    return mydata;
});

app.controller('PriorityPlacement',['$scope', '$rootScope','myplacementdata', function($scope, $rootScope,myplacementdata){  
  var response.Data=[{city_name: "Toronto", city_placement_charge: "1799"}, yolomd_verify: "50"];
    myplacementdata.setplacementdataValue=response.Data;
    console.log(myplacementdata.getplacementdataValue);
    //window.location = site_url + 'Overview'
   }]);
app.controller('Overview',['$scope', '$rootScope','$stateParams','myplacementdata', function($scope, $rootScope,myplacementdata){
    console.log(myplacementdata.getplacementdataValue);
   }])
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="yolomd">
<head>
  <script src="http://205.134.251.196/~examin8/CI/yoloMD/assets/front/js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that :

```
setplacementdataValue()
getplacementdataValue()
```

These are methods and not variables.

So use them as :

```
setplacementdataValue([Your Array Input]);
console.log(getplacementdataValue());
```

Note the parenthesis.

Also in your set method, use a different input parameter name.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('PriorityPlacement', ['myplacementdata',
  function(myplacementdata) {
    myplacementdata.setplacementdataValue([1, 2, 3]);
    console.log(myplacementdata.getplacementdataValue());
  }
]);

app.controller('Overview', ['myplacementdata',
  function(myplacementdata) {
    console.log(myplacementdata.getplacementdataValue());
  }
]);

app.service('myplacementdata', function() {
  var placementdata = [];
  this.getplacementdataValue = function() {
    return placementdata;
  }
  this.setplacementdataValue = function(myplacementdata) {
    placementdata = myplacementdata;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PriorityPlacement">
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="Overview">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on second controller it gives error --  angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getplacementdataValue' of undefined

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: On second controller it giving error --  Cannot read property 'getplacementdataValue' of undefined

Comment: one moment let me try jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

First off try changing

```
myplacementdata.setplacementdataValue=response.Data;
```

To

```
 myplacementdata.setplacementdataValue(response.Data);
```

And where do u get the response.Data from?

try using a factory instead. like so.

```
app.factory('myplacementdata', function () {
    var mydata = {

      placementdata = [],
      getplacementdataValue:function () {
         return mydata.placementdata; 
      },
      setplacementdataValue: function (data) {
        mydata.placementdata = data;
      }
    }
    return mydata;
});
```

Comment: For that there is an ajax request

Comment: done no response on same controller when I done console.log(myplacementdata.getplacementdataValue); after set

Comment: updated my answer check it out.

Comment: Aso getplacementdatavalue is a function so.. console.log(myplacementdata.getplacementdataValue());

Comment: Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: commonServiceProvider <-

Comment: How does your factory look now, are u injecting anything to it?

Comment: service.js:91 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Comment: Sounds like there is something else going on aswell.. jquery errors.?